# Best way to aggregate a list of items and collect totals

Tags: ruby, aggregate

I'm wondering if there's a good `fold` (or map, reduce etc.) style solution to this problem.

Give a collection of purchases (order_items) I want to gather the totals for each product/sku.

Example collection:

```
[{sku: "A", price:10}, 
 {sku: "B", price:5}, 
 {sku: "C", price:2}, 
 {sku: "B", price:5}, 
 {sku: "A", price:10}, 
 {sku: "B", price:5}]
```

And get a result of:

```
{"A":20, "B":15, "C":2}
```

At present I do it like so:

```
aggregate = order_items.each_with_object({}){|i,o|
  o[i[:sku]] ||= 0
  o[i[:sku]] += i[:price]
}
```

Which gives me what I want, but I want to know if there's a more elegant way to do this?

Obviously, if I pre-filter to a single SKU I can do a classic `reduce` ie.

```
# assuming sku is a flat array of values for a single sku type...
aggregate_sku = sku.reduce(:+)
```

However, I don't want to have to pre-filter the original collection. Is there a way to  achieve this or am I already doing everything possible?

Any help is appreciated.

Edited to add clarity to the question. If you feel the need to vote to close, please post a comment first, so I can clarify.

Subtext: I'm not sure if `map`, `reduce` etc, has features (or more likely techniques) I don't yet understand, Thank you.

Comment: To the kind person who's voted to close this, and is unclear what I'm asking... : I'm wondering if there's a better solution to this problem. Possibly using `map` (etc.)

Comment: I'd use `inject` instead of `each_with_object`, but apart from that your solution should at least be one of the fastest :)

Comment: @tessi I tried with `reduce` (a psedonym of `inject`) but I couldn't figure out what was going wrong, can you post an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
order_items = [
 {sku: "A", price:10}, 
 {sku: "B", price:5}, 
 {sku: "C", price:2}, 
 {sku: "B", price:5}, 
 {sku: "A", price:10}, 
 {sku: "B", price:5}
]

aggregate = order_items.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |item, acc|
  acc[ item[:sku] ] += item[:price]
end

--output:--
{"A"=>20, "B"=>15, "C"=>2}
```

Comment: Hi @7stud I'd already given tessi a point for the contribution. Thanks for the improved answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by)

```
agg = order_items.group_by { |item| item.sku }
agg.each { |sku, items| agg[sku] = items.map(&:price).reduce(:+) }
```

Comment: Many thanks, not quite what I'm looking for, but useful info.

Answer (score 1):

```
order_items.inject(Hash.new) {|hash, item| hash[item[:sku]] = (hash[item[:sku]] || 0) + item[:price]; hash}
```

It uses `inject` instead of `each_with_object` and simplifies the `nil` case in the aggregation. But it's more or less the same as in your question.

---

Please have a look at @7stud's answer, he does handles the `0` default value in a better way.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like what I'm after, the `nil` case was the smell.

Comment: I gave yours an upvote - and thought it is a good idea to update the accepted answer. But your're right, I should have edited it in a way to reflect that. Didn't want to offend you.

Comment: @7Stud don't worry, yours is a better answer, I'll re-assign acceptance. (I didn't see tessi's edit anyway)

Comment: @Slomojo, No matter.  I'm sure you taught me more than I taught you.  I'm going to start using each_with_object instead of reduce/inject, so that I don't have to frivolously return the accumulator.

Comment: Ruby's Enumerator methods are so plentiful that it's tough to have them all in mind all the time.