# Best way to aggregate a simple dict in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, count, aggregate

My problem is simple: I have a list of dicts, and I want to make a count aggregation of this into a new dictionary, on a particular key. Just like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873046/best-way-to-aggregate-a-list-of-items-and-collect-totals), but in Python.

### Original data

```
mylist = [
    {'date': '16-01-2016', 'name': 'A'},
    {'date': '16-01-2016', 'name': 'B'},
    {'date': '17-01-2016', 'name': 'C'},
    {'date': '17-01-2016', 'name': 'D'},
    {'date': '17-01-2016', 'name': 'E'},
    {'date': '18-01-2016', 'name': 'F'},
]
```

### Result

```
{'17-01-2016': 3, '16-01-2016': 2, '18-01-2016': 1}
```

### How to?

What is the best solution to achieve this? I would like to do it a more beautiful and pythonic way than that ugly piece of code:

```
result = {}
for item in mylist:
    if not item['date'] in result:
        result[item['date']] = 1
    else:
        result[item['date']] += 1
```

Many thanks for considering my request!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [*collections.Counter*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) dict with *map* and [*operator.itemgetter*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html):

```
from collections import Counter
from operator import itemgetter

mylist = [
    {'date': '16-01-2016', 'name': 'A'},
    {'date': '16-01-2016', 'name': 'B'},
    {'date': '17-01-2016', 'name': 'C'},
    {'date': '17-01-2016', 'name': 'D'},
    {'date': '17-01-2016', 'name': 'E'},
    {'date': '18-01-2016', 'name': 'F'},
]

counts = Counter(map(itemgetter("date"), mylist))
```

Output:

```
Counter({'17-01-2016': 3, '16-01-2016': 2, '18-01-2016': 1})
```

Or using just a gen exp:

```
counts = Counter(d["date"] for d in mylist)
```

If you are using *python2*, use [itertools.imap](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.imap) in place of map.

On a side note, `if item['date'] not in result` reads better than `if not item['date'] in result`.

If speed really matters, the map and itemgetter will be a little faster:

```
In [16]: timeit  Counter(map(itemgetter("date"), mylist))
10 loops, best of 3: 23.9 ms per loop

In [17]: timeit  Counter(d["date"] for d in mylist)
10 loops, best of 3: 26.8 ms per loop

In [18]: timeit Counter(map(lambda x: x['date'], mylist))
10 loops, best of 3: 34.9 ms per loop
```

Comment: I'm partial to the generator expression version -- fewer imports, shorter code, easier to read ... What's not to like?  :-).

Comment: @mgilson,  some folk,  including myself like the old functional approach ;) I also knew map would rear its head at some stage and most likely with a lambda.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `Counter`

```
from collections import Counter 

Counter(map(lambda x: x['date'], mylist))
# Counter({'17-01-2016': 3, '16-01-2016': 2, '18-01-2016': 1})
```

`Counter` is a `dict` subclass, so you don't have to worry about having `Counter` prefixing your printed result.